# Detect Back Button in Navigation Guards of Vue-Router

Tags: javascript, cordova, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

How the route is changed, matters for my case.
So, I want to catch when the route is changed by a back button of browser or gsm.

This is what I have:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if ( /* IsItABackButton && */ from.meta.someLogica) {
    next(false) 
    return ''
  }
  next()
})
```

Is there some built-in solutions that I can use instead of `IsItABackButton` comment? Vue-router itself hasn't I guess but any workaround could also work here. Or would there be another way preferred to recognize it?

Comment: please read this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2796#issuecomment-498348465

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the only way that I've found:

We can listen for popstate, save it in a variable, and then check that variable

```
// This listener will execute before router.beforeEach only if registered
// before vue-router is registered with Vue.use(VueRouter)

window.popStateDetected = false
window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
  window.popStateDetected = true
})


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const IsItABackButton = window.popStateDetected
  window.popStateDetected = false
  if (IsItABackButton && from.meta.someLogica) {
    next(false) 
    return ''
  }
  next()
})
```

Comment: I was expecting a better solution from Navigation-Guards for this problem but probaby this is indeed currently the only thing what we can do about this problem.

Comment: @Nuno Balbona Pérez, it looks like the popstate event handler runs *AFTER* the router.beforeEach callback. I don't think this would work just as is.

Comment: upvoted! where are you putting this code? inside router.js? i am using nuxt here

Comment: To take care of calling order problem It's possible to timeout or nextick-wrap beforeEach logic. Not elegant, but this solution works quite well. Bigger problem is that this solution also reacts to forward-btn click - but to be fair question doesn't say anything about it lol

Comment: how does this work on nuxt 2

Answer (score 7):

Slight improvement to @yair-levy answer.

Wrapping `push` to own `navigate` method is not convenient because you usually want to call `push`() from various places. Instead, router original methods can be patched in one place without changes in remaining code.

Following code is my Nuxt plugin to prevent navigation triggered by back/forward buttons (used in Electron app to avoid back caused by mouse additional "back" button, which makes mess in Electron app)
Same principle can be used for vanilla Vue and to track common back button together with your custom handling.

```
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  // this is Nuxt stuff, in vanilla Vue use just your router intances 
  const { router } = app

  let programmatic = false
  ;(['push', 'replace', 'go', 'back', 'forward']).forEach(methodName => {
    const method = router[methodName]
    router[methodName] = (...args) => {
      programmatic = true
      method.apply(router, args)
    }
  })

  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    // name is null for initial load or page reload
    if (from.name === null || programmatic) {
      // triggered bu router.push/go/... call
      // route as usual
      next()
    } else {
      // triggered by user back/forward 
      // do not route
      next(false)
    }
    programmatic = false // clear flag
  })
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As stated by @Yuci, all the router hook callbacks are performed *before* popstate is updated (and therefore not helpful for this use case)

What you can do:

```
methods: {
    navigate(location) {
        this.internalNavigation = true;
        this.$router.push(location, function () {
            this.internalNavigation = false;
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

1. Wrap 'router.push' with you own 'navigate' function
2. Before calling router.push, set 'internalNavigation' flag to true
3. Use vue router 'oncomplete' callback to set internalNavigation flag back to false

Now you can check the flag from within beforeEach callback and handle it accordingly.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if ( this.internalNavigation ) {
      //Do your stufff
  }
  next()
})
```

Answer (score 5):

I found a simple way to solve this after spending a lot of time trying to refine the codes to work well in my case and without a glitch.

```
export const handleBackButton = () => {
    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
        if (window.event.type == 'popstate' && from.name == 'HomePage'){  
            next(false);
        }else{  
            next(); 
        }
    });
}
```

- The `window.event.type == 'popstate'` checks if the back button is pressed
- And `from.name == 'HomePage'` checks the page on which the back button is pressed or you are routing from.
- HomePage as the name where you want to disable back button. You can leave this condition if you want to disable it throughout the site.
- `next(false) and next()` to stop or allow navigation respectively.
- You can place the code in a navigationGuard.js file and import it to your main.js file
- I tried other methods, including calling from the components but it produces a glitch and the rerouting becomes obvious. But this leaves no glitch at all.

Hope this works for you. Cheers

Comment: in my case, this works better than the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

There is a build-in method in Vue Router Api that can help to solve this challenge. See here: https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/RouterHistory.html#listen

Here is the idea:

```js
// /src/router/index.ts

// outer variable to track if the back button was used
let navigationInfo = null;
router.options.history.listen((to, from, info) => {
  // we cannot control navigation flow from here
  // just apply some side effects
  navigationInfo = info;
});

router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
  if (navigationInfo && navigationInfo.direction === 'back') {
    // do whatever you want
  }
});
```

In my case I was trying to intercept a mobile browser back button click to manually navigate 1 level up from the current page. I ended up with a code like this:

```js
let direction = "";
router.options.history.listen((to, from, info) => {
  direction = info.direction;
});

router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
  const isBackNavigation = direction === "back";
  // reset outer varialbe
  direction = "";

  // back-navigation path should not be longer that the current one, right?
  if (isBackNavigation && to.path.length > from.path.length) {
    // construct a sliced "1 level up" path
    return from.path.split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/");
  }
});
```

Worth to mention that to make a "1 level up" strategy work properly you should have a corresponding route to /every/path/part of a URL address.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.The Dark Knight

Comment: I find a little bug and fix it.

Comment: @hezf it would be nice to share what this little bug is and how did you fix it.

Comment: I have shared in this question, and make a [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-browser-navigation-in-vue-router)

Comment: look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77959713/6647700)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem regarding detecting Back Button navigation as opposed to other types of navigation in my Vue App.

What I ended up doing was adding a hash to my real internal App navigation to differentiate between intended App navigation and Back Button navigation.

For example, on this route `/page1` I want to catch Back Button navigations to close models that are open. Imagine I really wanted to navigate to another route, I'll add a hash to that route: `/page2#force`

```
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    // if no hash then handle back button
    if (!to.hash) {
      handleBackButton();
      next(false); // this stops the navigation
      return;
    }
    next(); // otherwise navigate
}
```

This is rather simplistic, but it works. You'll want to check what the hash actually contains if you use them for more than this in your app.

Answer (score 1):

performance.navigation is deprecated so whatch out! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/navigation

When you want to register any global event listener you should be very careful with that. It will be called each time since registration moment untill you unregister that manualy. For me the case was that I have register popstate listener when component was created to listen and call some action when:

- browser back button
- alt + arrow back
- back button in mouse

was clicked. After that I have unregister popstate listener to not call it in other components where I don't want it to be called, keep Your code and method calls clean :).

My code sample:

```
    created() {
      window.addEventListener('popstate', this.popstateEventAction );
    },
    methods: {
      popstateEventAction() {
        // ... some action triggered when the back button is clicked
        this.removePopstateEventAction();
      },
      removePopstateEventAction() {
        window.removeEventListener('popstate', this.popstateEventAction);
      }
   }
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer *almost* worked for me, but I found that the listener was behind by 1 click, probably due to the issue that @Yuci highlighted.

The answer from @farincz worked best for me, but since it wasn't written for vanilla Vue, I thought I'd write down what worked for me here:

```
// after createRouter
let programmatic = false;
(['push', 'replace', 'go', 'back', 'forward']).forEach(methodName => {
  const method = router[methodName]
  router[methodName] = (...args) => {
    programmatic = true
    method.apply(router, args)
  }
})

router.beforeEach(async (to, from) => {
  if(!from.name === null || !programmatic) {
    // do stuff you want to do when hitting back/forward or reloading page
  }
  programmatic = false // clear flag
});
```

Comment: I tried the code, but when I want to trigger a navigation with router.push('/home')  or just return '/home'  at the place of    '// do stuff ...'     nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

My inspiration comes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77828857/6647700)  and I fix a little bug.

```
let navigationInfo = null
router.options.history.listen((to, from, info) => {
  // we cannot control navigation flow from here
  // just apply some side effects
  navigationInfo = info
})

router.beforeEach(() => {
  if (navigationInfo) {
    if (navigationInfo.direction === 'back') {
      console.log('back')
    } else if (navigationInfo.direction === 'forward') {
      console.log('forward')
    }
    // need to reset it to null
    navigationInfo = null
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

0

The above worked well for me, but I needed to put a delay on the reset of popStateDetected back to false. Otherwise my intended nav didn't work first time after the blocked nav. Apart from that, thanks so much. This is in the router/index.js of my Quasar 2.9 (Vue.js 3) PWA.

```js
import { route } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import { createRouter, createMemoryHistory, createWebHistory, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes'
import { useAuthStore } from 'stores/auth'

/*
 * If not building with SSR mode, you can
 * directly export the Router instantiation;
 *
 * The function below can be async too; either use
 * async/await or return a Promise which resolves
 * with the Router instance.
 */

window.popStateDetected = false
window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
  window.popStateDetected = true
})

export default route(function (/* { store, ssrContext } */) {
  const createHistory = process.env.SERVER
    ? createMemoryHistory
    : (process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE === 'history' ? createWebHistory : createWebHashHistory)

  const Router = createRouter({
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ left: 0, top: 0 }),
    routes,

    // Leave this as is and make changes in quasar.conf.js instead!
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> vueRouterMode
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> publicPath
    history: createHistory(process.env.MODE === 'ssr' ? void 0 : process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE)
  })

  Router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
    const IsItABackButton = window.popStateDetected
    setTimeout(() => {window.popStateDetected = false}, 250)
    // instead of having to check every route record with
    // to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)
    const auth = useAuthStore()
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !auth.isLoggedIn) {
      console.log('Not logged in.')
      // this route requires auth, check if logged in
      // if not, redirect to login page.
      return {
        path: '/login',
        // save the location we were at to come back later
        query: { redirect: to.fullPath },
      }
    }
    if (IsItABackButton && from.name === 'Stocktake') {
      return false
    }
  })

  return Router
})
```

Comment: You should create a new question by add question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Answer (score -4):

This is done very easily.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [...],
  scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (savedPosition) {
      // History back position, if user click Back button
      return savedPosition
    } else {
      // Scroll to top of page if the user didn't press the back button
      return { x: 0, y: 0 }
    }
  }
})
```

Check here:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#async-scrolling

Comment: Can you explain how this works to detect that a back button was detected? How to use this to solve the OP's written problem? How does the `scrollBehavior` event fire in relation to `beforeEach` ?

Comment: You can also add `to.meta.fromHistory = (savedPosition !== null);` if you need to let the rest of the app know it’s from back/forward.