# How to set up Vue routes or override back button to function like an app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am building a cordova Vue app. In many cases there is deeper links like this

`/profile/:id/:contact_type/contacts:contact_id`

Where you would first be on `/profile/:id` and then click a link to go to `/profile/:id/:contact_type/contacts:contact_id`

The standard `router.go(-1)` works fine if you were on the profile page first.  But if you get a notification or something, and are sent from any page, for example `/settings/:id`.  Your back button should behave more like an Up button, pressing back on `/profile/:id/:contact_type/contacts:contact_id` should take you to `/profile/:id` and not `/settings/:id`.
How do I set this up?  I tried a few things like splitting the current route on `/` and popping it, then joining back and pushing to that.  But that doesn't work with parameters, especially if there is more than 1.

```
const path = router.currentRoute.path
const URLSplit = path.split('/')
URLSplit.length = URLSplit.length - 1
const newTarget = URLSplit.join('/')
if (newTarget) {
  router.push(newTarget)
} else {
  router.push('/home')
}
```

I also tried using child routes, but that requires a `router-view` in each page, which isn't what I want to do.

I have already captured the back button operation, I just want to know if there is a way to set up Vue to do this sort of back operation, or is there a way I am supposed to set up the router to do this, or a function that can figure out the current route and go up to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like it would defeat the original purpose of navigating between historical/visited pages (rather than going up one level in the routes).

I would instead add a dedicated, in-app back button for this (like Google apps do have one); otherwise, you might have to try and intercept the browser's default behavior for that particular button, by listening to the [`popstate` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event) of the `Window` interface which is fired when the active history entry changes. But if you have to, there is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52721706/3634538) for that with [Global Before (navigation) Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#navigation-guards).

With an in-app back (or technically "up") button I mentioned earlier, you could use [In-Component Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards).

For example, given the following `routes` settings...

```js
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/profile/:id',
      name: 'profile',
      component: Profile,

      children: [{
        path: ':contact_type/contacts:contact_id',
        name: 'contact',
        component: Contact
      }]
    }
  ]
})
```

...you would directly define the route navigation guards inside the route component (e.g. `Contacts.vue`):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'profile' }">&lt;- back to profile</router-link>

    Some contact information.
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
      if (from.name === 'contact' && to.name !== 'profile') {
        next({
          name: 'profile',
          params: {
            id: from.params.id
          }
        });
      }
      else {
        next();
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Not necessarily the best approach, but that should work.