# How to trigger an alert, when the back button of the browser is passed in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to trigger an alert message once the user clicks the back button of a webpage. I am trying the following way:

```
import LeavePopup from '../../global/js/leave-popup';
import ScrollTo from '../../global/js/scroll-to';
import UrlHandler from '../../global/js/url-handler';

import Vue from 'vue';
import SignUpForm from '../../global/js/components/SignUpForm';
import VideoPlayer from '../../global/js/components/VideoPlayer';
import JustMadeMoney from '../../global/js/components/JustMadeMoney';
import Carousel from 'vue-owl-carousel'

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    LeavePopup.bind('.modal');
    ScrollTo.bind();
    UrlHandler.handle('additionalParams');
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    components: {
        VideoPlayer,
        SignUpForm,
        Carousel,
        JustMadeMoney
    },
    mounted() {
        // if back button is pressed
        window.onpopstate = function(event) {
          alert("Back button clicked");
        };
     }
});
```

but currently nothing happens, how can I properly catch the click of the back button?

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a navigation guard. Per the vue-router [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards),

`The leave guard is usually used to prevent the user from accidentally leaving the route with unsaved edits. The navigation can be canceled by calling next(false).`

The example below is from the Vue docs. You can modify it to suit your needs.

```js
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
  const answer = window.confirm('Do you really want to leave? you have unsaved    changes!')
  if (answer) {
    next()
  } else {
    next(false)
  }
})
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56331630/how-to-set-up-vue-routes-or-override-back-button-to-function-like-an-app) supports the above method

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980296/detect-back-button-in-navigation-guards-of-vue-router) uses a different method.

Comment: There is no way to somehow trigger an event on the browser's back button?

Comment: There is. This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980296/detect-back-button-in-navigation-guards-of-vue-router helps with that. You can check it out.