# How to change router back route in vuejs2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have an Vue Application with a home view and two other side views.
I want to redirect all back button presses of the two side views to the home view, what is the best way to do this in the latest vuejs version (2.6.10)?

I am currently using the vue-router without history mode enabled, however all back button pressed are still redirected to the last view.

I have already tried to add "backbutton" event listeners on the side views, but it didn't change anything.

Here is my code of one of the side views.

```
<template>
  <h1>Left View</h1>
</template>

<script>
import router from '../router'

export default {
  name: 'left',
  methods: {
    goToHomePage() {
      router.push('/')
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', this.goToHomePage, false)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    document.removeEventListener('backbutton', this.goToHomePage)
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the back button in the code? Simply call that method `goToHomePage()` on the button click `<button @click="goToHomePage">Go Back</button>`. Also those event listeners mean nothing (no event known as `backbutton`)

Comment: Seems you're looking for go : https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-go-n

Comment: The back button is the browsers back button, is the 'backbutton' event not the right one?

Comment: @MarcoRodriguez `backbutton` event is used in [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.backbutton.html). Are you building app on that (Mobile apps)?

Comment: Can you create a plunker to replicate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try similar approach like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980296/detect-back-button-in-navigation-guards-of-vue-router). The point is to intercept all route changes and decide, where you want to go.