# How to detect broswer back button in Vue-router navigation guard

Tags: javascript, vue.js, browser, vue-router

How do I make sure the browser back button does not work since I have router navigation setup. If I'm not authenticated, I don't want to go to my home page but clicking the back button still works. Any help on this, turns out Vue router doesn't handle this? I want to catch when the route is changed by a back button of the browser.

This is what I have:

```vue
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (user.currentUser) {
      console.log(user.currentUser);
      next();
    } else {
      next({ path: "/login" });
    }
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect Back Button in Navigation Guards of Vue-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980296/detect-back-button-in-navigation-guards-of-vue-router)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I tried that but it didn't. Can't figure out why