# How can I detect the browser back button with Vue?

Tags: vue.js

In my component I need to do some logic when the user is navigate to my component using browser "back" button.

Maybe there is a property in vue router or something similar?

How can I detect the browser back button with Vue?

Comment: Maybe this is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980296/detect-back-button-in-navigation-guards-of-vue-router

Comment: no, because I need to know if the action was "back" in my component.. in create event..

Comment: also, popstate happens after router.beforeEach. I think something like route.isback I looking..

Answer (score 0):

You can use popstate event,

```js
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
   // do something
   console.log(event);
});
```

Comment: note that it also will be triggered on browser forward button clicked