# Commit initial array to store when leaving page, but if pressing back button loads last commited array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have an array of articles that can be filtered based on their category. If you click the filter for "ideas" it will filter the array into a new array, let's say "ideasFiltered" and then i commit it to my store "filteredArticles". If i leave the page and press back it is saving that info. Yay! Great! BUT, let's say i go to a new page in my website and then i click my news page again, it has still saved that last commit "ideasFiltered". Is there a way to only save that data if you are pressing "back" in the browser or pressing "back to articles" out of one of my articles (i have a button that let's you go back to the list of articles on each article page), but if you click to a different link in my site it will reset to my full article list?

here is my store:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
 state: {
   filteredArticles: this.articles
 },
 mutations: {
   setFilteredList (state, value) {
     state.filteredArticles = value
   }
 },
 plugins: [
   createPersistedState()
 ],
})
```

my computed:

```
computed: {
  filteredArticles () {
     return store.state.filteredArticles
  }
}
```

so if you click one of my filtered is runs a script, here is an example of the ideas script

```
ideas: function ideas() {
  this.$store.commit('setFilteredList', articles) **// resetting to the full list before filtering**

  var ideasFiltered = this.filteredArticles.filter(function(post) {
     return post.category === 'Ideas';
  });

  this.filteredCategory = 'ideas'; **// this is used to add the category to my url**

  this.$store.commit('setFilteredList', ideasFiltered) **// committing to the store**
}
```

here is my html, not sure if it is really necessary though

```
<div class="news-article-list">
  <ul>
     <li v-for="(article, index) in filteredArticles" :key="index">
       <a :href="article.url">
         <img :src="article.featureImg" v-if="article.featureImg" alt="Article Feature Image" />
         <h2 class="news-title">{{ article.title }}</h2>
         <p class="news-date">{{ article.date }}</p>
         <p class="short-desc">{{ article.shortDesc }}...</p>
       </a>
       <router-link class="read-more" :to="article.url">Read More</router-link>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Let me know if i need to explain any further. I need it to commit ALL articles if going to a different page on my site and clicking news to get back to the news page, but saving the FILTERED article list if you go to an article and click back.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of Vue.js are you using? I would recommend adding a watch to the route and then depending on which route.name you go to, you can decide how you want your store to be manipulated.

Comment: v2.6.13
How would i go about that? I know i have my router looking for params to see what category i selected and what page i am on. Is it the same premise? here is what i use for my currentPage and filteredCategory -
currentPage: this.$route.params.currentPage || 1,
filteredCategory: this.$route.params.filteredCategory || 'all-categories'

Comment: to add, i am only using vuejs on my article list page. Would that still work if my other pages aren't using vue ?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52721706/11545271 to detect if you clicked the back button. You can use this to send I prop to the component if you need to use the filtered data or regular data.

Comment: but, again, i don't have components. I am using vue on this one page only. So would this still work?

Comment: I added the functionality discussed in the post you added and it does seem to be working, but it is breaking how my pagination/filtering works. I barely understand the code in the link you sent so i have no idea how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about detecting the back button. What you want to know where `from`  did the user come and where `to` the user wants to go. `to` and `from` are your routes. `ideasFiltered` is changed permanently until you clear it manually. To handle clearing it yourself, create an `action` in `vue-router` that resets the data in `ideasFiltered` and then `dispatch` that action depending on what route the user is on. You can add a `watch` in your Vue component to watch the global vue-router `$router`. In Vue.js 3 its like this:

```
import {useRoute} from 'vue-router';
import {useStore} from 'vuex';
....

setup() {
const $route = useRoute();
const $store = useStore();
  watch(() => $route.name, async () => {
// If the user is not on News or Articles route, then tell store to reset filtered list
    if ($route.name !=== "News" || $route.name !=== "Articles") {
      $store.dispatch('clearFilteredList', null) // You need to create this action in your store
    },
    {
      deep: true,
      immediate: true
    }
)
}
```

The `mutation` and `action` in `$store` to be committed would be something like:

```
mutations: {
   setFilteredList (state, value) { // value passed should be null
     state.filteredArticles = value
   }
actions: {
    clearFilteredList({commit}, payload) { // This is null from Vue component remember!
    commit('setFilteredList', payload) // sets it to null
}
```

I can't see your full store code so the above answer is a best guess but should give you an idea how to go about it. You don't have to use `null`, you could use make it an empty array or object e.g. `[]`