# how can I use router.back() in vue without a button

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

So my current project use vue and its packages, I want to navigate to the last page without using a physical button coded into the app, I want to navigate using the browser's button the ones under the tab above the window.

```
const history = createWebHistory();
const router = createRouter({
  routes,
  history,
});

/***********/

export default router;
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: most of them are typical setups, I want the router.back() to be here,any sugesstion?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the back button play nice with client-side routing, you could [change your history mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html) and add a server. If you're trying to override default behavior, you can use [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards). You can check `popstate` as in some of [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980296/detect-back-button-in-navigation-guards-of-vue-router?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top) to detect if the navigation actually came from your code or not, but note that the Vue Router code in those solutions is mostly outdated.